# I can't solve symbolically a linear equation to a variable, even though it's super simple to do it manualy

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am very frustrated currently because I have a realistically simple equation with symbols that  can't be solved to a variable. Even when done manually, it gives an error (numerically to the order of `10^{-17}`) when substituting.

I can't post a mwe example so I'll post the most simplified form of the problem.

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy import sqrt, Derivative
r          = sy.Symbol('r')
uf         = sy.Function('uf')
Expression =-4.5*r*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*uf(r)/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*sqrt(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*uf(r)**2 + 1.0*(r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - 1.0*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(1.0*r*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*uf(r)/((r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(3/2)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) + 0.5*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*uf(r)/((r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(3/2)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)**2) + 0.5*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(-2*r*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*uf(r) + 4*(r - 1)*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*uf(r) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(2*(1 - r)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62))*uf(r) + 2*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) + 1.62*r - 1.62)*uf(r) + 2*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*Derivative(uf(r), r) + 2*(r*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81) + (1 - r)*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33))*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*uf(r))/((r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(3/2)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)**2))*uf(r)/(sqrt(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) + 0.5*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-1.8*r*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(7/2)*(2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*sqrt(1/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*uf(r) - 2.0*r*(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)**2 + 1.0*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(7/2)*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*sqrt(1/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*uf(r) + 1.0*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**(7/2)*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*sqrt(1/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*uf(r) + 2.0*sqrt((-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**4*(-0.9*r*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - (0.9*r*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33) - (r**2 - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)**2*sqrt(1/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)))/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)**5*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)**2*sqrt(1/(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81))) + 2.5*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*uf(r)/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*sqrt(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*uf(r)**2 + 1.0*(r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) + 2.5*sqrt((r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*uf(r)/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*sqrt(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*uf(r)**2 + 1.0*(r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - 2.5*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)*uf(r)**2/((r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*uf(r)**2 + 1.0*(r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) + (-0.9*r*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(0.9*r*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33) - (r**2 - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2)*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)/(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33) + (-0.9*r*(1.8*r*(-2*r*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + (r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*(4*r*(r**2 + 0.81) - 1.62*r + 1.62)) + (1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561)) - (0.9*r*(1.8*r**2 - 5.46662440780247e-33) - (r**2 - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))*(1.0*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*uf(r)**2/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + 1)*(r**2 - 2*r + 0.81)**2/((-3.24*r**2 + (-r**2 + 2*r - 3.03701355989026e-33)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))**2*(-1.0*(r**2 + 3.03701355989026e-33)*uf(r)**2/(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561) + 1.0)*(-0.81*r**2 + 1.62*r + (r**2 + 0.81)**2 - 0.6561))
sy.solve(Expression,sy.diff(uf(r),r))
```

you can verify that the equation is very simple to solve with respect to `sy.diff(uf(r),r)` since  `sy.diff(Expression,sy.diff(uf(r),r),1)` is non zero and `sy.diff(Expression,sy.diff(uf(r),r),2)` is `0`.

The above solver crushes my kernel when using jupyter and I have to solve it manually 
-`solution = (Expression-sy.diff(Expression,sy.diff(uf(r),r),1)*sy.diff(uf(r),r))/(-sy.diff(Expression,sy.diff(uf(r),r),1))`- still is not fully accurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to solve this using SymPy tools even though this is an unwieldy expression. The goal is to reduce the number of symbols that must be tracked and manipulated:

0) replace the derivative with z to make it easier to track

```
>>> from sympy import diff
>>> from sympy.abc import z
>>> y = Expression.subs(diff(uf(r), r), z)
```

1) extract common subexpressions

```
>>> from sympy import cse
>>> reps, e = cse(y)
```

2) e is a list, get the expression

```
>>> e = e[0]
```

3) expand e

```
>>> e = e.expand(); type(e)
Add
```

4) isolate z

```
>>> i, d = e.as_independent(z); type(d)
Mul
```

5) solve for z

```
>>> sol = i/d.coeff(z)
```

6) restore extracted patterns (in reverse order)

```
>>> sol = sol.subs(reps[::-1]); sol.count_ops()
1584
```

Putting it all together we have this fallback:

```
def unwieldy_linear_solve(eq, x):
    from sympy import cse
    if not x.is_Symbol:
        d = Dummy()
        return unwieldy_linear_solve(eq.subs(x, d), d)
    r, e = cse(eq)
    i, d = e[0].expand().as_independent(x)
    assert d == x or d.is_Mul and x in d.args
    c, z = d.as_independent(x)
    assert z == x
    sol = i/c
    for o,n in r[::-1]:
        sol = sol.xreplace({o:n})
    return sol

>>> count_ops(unwieldy_linear_solve(Expression, diff(uf(r),r)))
1584
```

Comment: Hi there, really thank you, once again. Really had no time answering yesterday and when I got break totally forgot to (solved it manually cuz I wanted to proceed). Just out of interest, why doesn't sympy solve it normally and quick? Doesn't it have any algorithm that identify it as easy and linear form realtive to the variable, therefore proceed to a quicker solution itself?

Comment: Yes, it does try to do that. It would be interesting to see if this approach is faster for simple equations than what we currently do. If not, then this represents `yao` (yet another optimization). :-)

Comment: I suspect that much of the slowdown could be eliminated if the diff algorithm were improved.

Comment: solution discussed here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8191